# Mock device data on android tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking

The devices running my android app now can send their data to a server. But I'm having trouble testing, as the device's data change from device to device.

Here's how I get some of the device data:

```
    String simSerialNumber = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getSimSerialNumber();
    String androidVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    String deviceModel = Build.MODEL;
    String deviceSerial =  Build.SERIAL;
```

How can I mock these on my tests?

Comment: I'd put them in a separate class that can be mocked. Even though you can mock Context \ TelephonyManager (with Mockito, for instance), mocking Build.SERIAL, etc. will be harder. You can try Robolectric (it already faking some of the SystemProperties), or if you're using using in Android Studio you can provide your own implementation of android.os.SystemProperties.

Comment: @IuriiO I created many accessor functions with default visibility in a helper class so I could mock'em. Your comment guided me in the right way though. Can you post it as an answer, listing the mocking options in this case? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found a really convenient way to mock device information from this posting:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/-d4aaAGB7Ks

If you use Roboelectric, you can use ReflectionHelpers class.

```
ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(android.os.Build.class, "MANUFACTURER", "Manufacturer of your choice");
```